# Issue while using Pandas.Series.Apply function with Regular Expressions

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I'm trying to apply regular expressions on a specific column in a Data Frame.

This column is called '**weight**' of datatype 'non-null object'.
A **sample value** in this column looks like this -- '250 lbs./ 113.4 kg.'

My aim is to apply regular expressions on this entire column so as to extract only the weight in lbs (in the above example, this would be '250').

To this end, I used the Series.Apply function to apply regular expressions on every row of the column:

```
import re

k = Df['weight'].apply(re.findall,args=('^([0-9]+)\s+',))

print(k.head())
```

But for some reason, *'k' turns out to be a Pandas Series containing **empty lists.***

I tried to apply `re.findall` one by one on individual elements in the 'weight' column, and there it is returning the output as expected:

```
k = re.findall('^([0-9]+)\s+',Df['weight'].iloc[0])
print(k)
```

This would return an output of ['250'], if we tried it out for the above mentioned sample value.

Why is it that `re.findall` works fine when applied individually on an element of the Series, but doesn't work with Series.Apply function? I couldn't understand why I was getting a Series full of empty lists as output for the latter.

Comment: Check out `pandas.Series.str.extract` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html. It provides a nice way to create new columns from regex capture groups.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that served my purpose! It is returning the output I needed. I'd still like to know why I'm not getting the output for my code with re.findall, though...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a partial function into apply, or simply use a lambda

```
Df['weight'].apply(lambda x:re.findall('^([0-9]+)\s+',x))
```

Comment: Oh, understood. But are you saying that I should not use a normal function with apply(), and I should use _only_ partial functions/lambda instead?

Comment: Using a normal function can only allow positional parameters AFTER the value in the series. Per pandas doc, args parameter takes: Positional arguments passed to func after the series value. This is not compatible with findall. It should work in many other cases